# Facebook Application using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I want to develop a Facebook application (it is a simple quiz with 3 questions) using ASP.NET, but this is the first time that I've even tried doing it. I have found lots of confusing information on the internet and I wanted to ask what is the best and most correct way to do it (an API or something) and if there is a simple tutorial to get me started. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've previously done this is to create a standard ASP.NET MVC application and use the .NET API:

http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/